SwiftUI: Stepper interfere with Binding variable
WHAT I NEED: I've a stepper to set a value. This value is completely different if user is using the app with different units.
WHAT'S THE PROBLEM: While I just play with the unit picker in the settings tab, the value (stored as @AppStorage in the settings tab) in the main tab updates correctly. When I touch the stepper and modify the value in the main tab, if I try to modify the unit in the settings tab, everything mess up! (While the value in the settings tab keeps updating correctly, the value displayed in the main tab doesn't).
SETTING TAB:
class
 Defaults: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("appUnits") var appUnits: String = ""
    @AppStorage("memorizedDensity") var density: Double = 0.794
}

struct settings: View {
    @ObservedObject var defaults = Defaults()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                HStack {
                    ViewThatFits {
                        Text("App default Units")
                    }
                    Spacer(minLength: 10)
                    Picker(selection: $defaults.appUnits, label: Text("Unit")) {
                        ForEach(["", ""], id: \.self) {riga in
                            Text(riga)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: defaults.appUnits) {newValue in
                        if newValue == "" {
                            defaults.density = 0.793
                        } else if newValue == "" {
                            defaults.density = 6.66
                        }
                        // I need to set a different value when the unit changes 
                        print(defaults.density)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 120)
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MAIN TAB:
struct stepper: View {
    @ObservedObject var defaults = Defaults()
    
    var body: some View { fuelDatas }
    
    var fuelDatas: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Fuel density")
            HStack {
                Text(defaults.density, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(defaults.appUnits == "" ? 3 : 2)))
                Text(defaults.appUnits == "" ? "g/ml" : "lb/US gal")
            }
            
            Stepper("", value: defaults.$density, in: defaults.appUnits == "" ? 0.750...0.850 : 6...7, step: defaults.appUnits == "" ? 0.001 : 0.01)
                .frame(width: 50.0)
        }
    }
}

I know I'm messing something with the binding stuff and I'm probably creating 2 sources of truth, but I can't find what's wrong in the code! Here's the sample project-

Why can’t you access (declare) the AppStorage properties directly in your views instead of wrapping them in a separate type? Also if you keep the type then you need to make sure you use the StateObject and ObservedObject property wrappers correctly.

I tried but I couldn't make them work as, with different tabs and different files for the view, the initialiser for the previews could't get datas and I couldn't find a way to make them work seamlessly, so I just found this solution which works...

What do you mean by "the initialiser for the previews could't get datas"?

By declaring a @Binding for a variable held in a different tab (so completely different view and file), the PreviewProvider gives me the error "Missing argument for parameter 'density' in call" and I couldn't figure out a way to go through this. That's why I used the Default class. Try the sample code I posted: declare the State var density in the main tab then declare a Binding var density in the setting tab.

Ideally, you should just declare the @AppStorages in your Views, instead of wrapping them in another Defaults class.
struct stepper: View {
    @AppStorage("appUnits") var appUnits: String = ""
    @AppStorage("memorizedDensity") var density: Double = 0.794

    ...
}

Your current actually works if you take the two views out of the TabView, so it seems like this is another one of those peculiarities that TabView has.
If you really want a Defaults object for some reason, one way to make this work is to make sure all your views use the same object.
struct settings: View {
    // do not initialise it here
    @ObservedObject var defaults: Defaults

    ...
}

struct stepper: View {
    // do not initialise it here
    @ObservedObject var defaults: Defaults

    ...
}

In your tab view, declare a @StateObject and pass it down to both the stepper and settings.
@StateObject var defaults = Defaults()

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationStack {
            stepper(defaults: defaults)
        }
        .tabItem { Label("stepper", systemImage: "1.circle") }
        
        NavigationStack {
            settings(defaults: defaults)
        }
        .tabItem { Label("setting", systemImage: "2.circle") }
    }
}

You can also pass it as an @EnvironmentObject,
NavigationStack {
    stepper()
}
.environmentObject(defaults)

...

struct stepper: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var defaults: Defaults

    ...
}


Honestly, I'm not a big fan of Defaults but it's just a walk around to makes everything works in the tabView... If I try to declare the State var density in the stepper View, and modify it in settings tab by declaring an instance of it as Binding var density (as I'd like to do), then I get the "Missing argument for parameter 'density' in call" in the settings PreviewProvider. I can shut it by using          'settings(density: .constant(0.8))' but then I get something even more messed!

@Matte.Car That is not what my answer said at all. If you want the preview to work with a view that takes a Binding, you should declare a @State in the preview provider, like this. Or use @Previewable @State if you are using #Preview { ... }, like this.

@Matte.Car But why do you want to use a @Binding in settings in the first place? I don't understand what you are trying to do now. What's wrong with @AppStorage like you are currently doing?
